# Low frame rate on Windows 7 64bit "Aero"

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon, aero, framerate

I am experiencing a strange problem. I have ATI hd 5770 graphics card with driver version 11.1. From last 7 days i am experiencing low frame rate(15-20) on Aero. Aero peek is not working smooth. some times it works good at 60-85 frames. All the games are working fine. the problem is with Aero and other desktop effects only.

Comment: Install anything new recently?

Comment: From this: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/36235-63-aero-stutter

Comment: First of all sorry for the repeated comment. Did not realise pressing Enter (mobile) will post the comment. Continuing, it seems that the workaround for now would be to turn of transparency. You could try and turn it back on again to see if the probleem disappears.